# Stop label from pushing input field below other inputs when in horizontal row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I stop labels from pushing down inputs when the browser window is small?  (Please see example)

I have tried using text-nowrap, but that just causes the labels to overlap.

What's a good Bootstrap way, or Bootstrap design approach to avoid this type of thing?

I need the inputs to remain in a horizontal row.  I have to use a label, and I can't shorten the actual words (That would fix my problems, but I can't do that in this implementation).  **ALSO, there are more inputs on this row to the right not displayed in this example, so I cannot adjust `col-`**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <section class="mt-2">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-3">
            <label for="LastPayDate">Last Pay Date</label>
            <input id="LastPayDate" name="LastPayDate" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-3">
            <label for="BasePay">Base Pay</label>
            <input id="BasePay" name="BasePay" class="form-control" type="text">
          </div>

        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You See there is no proper way other then you given it a proper width in which the whole label can reside . 
All you can do is increase the column width and it will work fine .

Answer (score 0):

try add CSS to the label element so all labels will be equal

```
label{
    background-color: green;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 11%;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
cursor: pointer;

}
```